# Как подстраить высоту блока

Tags: css

Как сделать так, чтобы блок подстраивался под высоту блока при изменения размера браузера и при этом чтобы блок был под шапкой.

Вот блок уходит за границу нижней части всей страницы, а нужно чтобы он прицепился к низу всей страницы и при этом не закрывал шапку и таким образом подстраивался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

получилось при помощи `height: calc(100vh-100px);`